# Do these SQL queries make sense for the given tables?

Tags: sql, database

[image]

Give the following two SQL tables I want to run two queries (venue_id is a foreign key with id from the venues table):

`SELECT venues.name FROM venues INNER JOIN users ON venues.venue_id = users.venue_id WHERE users.id = {param}`

To return the venue name associated with the user_id that was passed in

`SELECT users.name FROM users WHERE users.venue_id = {param] AND users.expiration_time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

To return all the current users with a given venue_id where the expiration_time is after the current time.

Do both these queries do what I expect them to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: What about testing it out?

Comment: Why not run those queries and check the results? Verify the results ARE as expected. This is the only way you will know.

Comment: Ya you pretty much are on the right track. What is your issue?

Comment: @alaboudi yeah, it works. Tried it out in a quick SQL sandbox as the others suggested.

Comment: @zulusam You should not be posting here like that. If you are able to try something so easily on a sandbox but didnt bother you will be susceptible to downvotes like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT venues.name FROM venues INNER JOIN users ON **venues.id** = users.venue_id WHERE users.id = {param}

SELECT users.name FROM users WHERE users.venue_id = {param] AND users.expiration_time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Both queries should be doing what you expect them to do